# what is the best way to test if a struct exists before inserting it in an array?

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, struct, coldfusion-8

This is about coldfusion...

I have an array of structs in which I would like to get only dictinct values.
What is the best way to test if a structure already exists in my array before inserting this one ?
Should it be possible to test this with contains(javacast(...)) ?

Thank you in advance,
Michel

Finally I found how to add a portion of code :)

```
<cfset count = 0>
<cfset foo = []>
<cfif this struct does not exists in the array...>
    <cfset count = count + 1>
    <cfset foo[count] = {key = currentBar.getValue(), value = anotherValueVar}
</cfif>
```

Hope this will help...

Thank you,
Michel

Comment: Please add some examples (what you have and what you are expecting) in your question to clarity it, this should help others to understand it.

Comment: @Sergii, here is a portion of code :)

Answer (score 3):

CF9:

```
if (!ArrayContains(structs, struct))
    arrayAppend(structs, struct);
```

CF8, try Java's contains() in java.util.List.  CF array extends java.util.Vector so I guess this will work:

```
if (structs.contains(struct))
    arrayAppend(foo, struct);
```

Comment: So, the example code: (but I see that I have to make a new answer :)

Comment: Sorry, I did not say that I am always on CF8. I think that arrayContains is coming with CF9...

Comment: @Michel - Yes, CF8 does not support ArraysContains. How big is your structure? If it is small, you might just loop. A few other ideas here http://www.coldfusioncookbook.com/entry/35/How-do-I-find-a-value-in-an-array Just keep in mind using the underlying/undocumented stuff can *somtimes* be tricky. It often has nuances/gotchas not found in regular CF code. For example, case sensitivity.

Comment: @Henry - No cast needed. Though casting to java.util.Vector is not allowed anyway, only to a primitive type or object array. Also, one nuance of contains(..) is that it may return `false` when `null`s are involved. Probably not an issue here. But something to watch out for if you use java objects.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an array of structs, use a query, and then do a `select distinct` query-of-queries on it.

```
<cfscript>
    q = QueryNew('key,value');

    // add a row to the query
    QueryAddRow(q, 1);
    QuerySetCell(q, 'key', currentBar.getValue());
    QuerySetCell(q, 'value', anotherValueVar);

</cfscript>
<!--- Now that all the (non-distinct) rows have been added. --->
<cfquery name="dq" dbtype="query">
    <!--- Have to escape the names "key" and "value" with brackets
          because they are reserved words in CF queries. --->
    select distinct [key], [value] from q
</cfquery>
```

Comment: I probably would not convert to a query just for this. But you raise an interesting point. If the goal is distinct values, a structure might be a better choice than an array. Structures only store unique keys. So `<cfset foo [ theKey &"_"& theValue] = { key=theKey,value=theValue }>` should result in unique values only.

Comment: @Leigh: Yes, that would do nicely. You could also avoid the string concatenation by using nested structs: `foo[theKey][theValue] = { key=theKey, value=theValue }`. Of course, now there's no reason (except possibly convenience) to actually store the {key,value} pairs, since that information is available in the keys themselves.

Comment: _**EDIT_ True. I expect the reason probably is convenience ;) ** You might also be able to use the structure as the key. ie `foo[theStruct] = theStruct`. Not sure if works for complex objects, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: Nope. I tried it and only strings are allowed. I must have been thinking java ;)